# Unexpected Output from solution of Begginer's C++ Exercise

Tags: c++

I needed to create some kind of a bus route handbook (just practicing around), so I wrote this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GenWay(int length){
    vector<string> res;
    string stop;
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        cin >> stop;
        res.push_back(stop);
    }
    return res;
}

int isVinMap(vector<string> vs, map<int,vector<string>> miv){
    for(const auto& [key, vvalue]:miv){
        if(vvalue == vs) return key;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int q=0;
    cin >> q;

    map<int,vector<string>> ways;
    string stop="";
    int command=0;
    int next_way = 1; //last+1 //last = 0

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        cin >> command;
        vector<string> new_way = GenWay(command);
        int check = isVinMap(new_way,ways);

        cout << check << !static_cast<bool>(check); //Debug code

        if(!static_cast<bool>(check)){
            cout << "New bus " << next_way << endl;
            ways[next_way] = GenWay(command); //next_way is not controlled by user
            next_way++;
        } else{
            cout << "Already exists for " << check << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here what it should do:

First input must be the quantity of coming commands. (q) (e.g. `4`) (no output)

There's only one command that can be processed after first, and it has next format: `number_of_bus_stops stop1 stop2 stop3...` (e.g. `2 m k`). It adds an entry to `map<int,vector<string>> ways`, about the marchrute (The number of marchrute is not defined by user, and is `next_way`, which should increase after each new entry). If the same marchrute appear in other entries, it tells that it already exist and print the number of marchrute which contains this way (`isVinMap` method checks that and gives the number of marchrute)(ways with different order of stops are different), and tells that new bus created by saying (e.g. `New bus 1`) if adding of an entry is succesful.

*However* it doesn't work as it supposed to. Output is nearly unpredictable. I'm working in EclipseIDE on Winx64 system and got this output:

```
>4
>2 m k
01New bus 1
>3 k r s
01New bus 2
20Already exists for 2
20Already exists for 2
```

Seems like cycle goes on for two more times, after first two commands, but it doesn't invite me to input anything.

And, of course, any criticism of the code is appreciated!
*and sorry for lack of documentation and commentaries in the code, it wasn't supposed that i would have needed to work for that long on this one.*

Comment: Please try to avoid `using namespace std;` because it is considered bad practice.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: Unrelated: `int isVinMap(vector<string> vs, map<int,vector<string>> miv` – you are aware that you produce *copies* of both vector and map? You should rather accept by const reference.

Comment: So you're working in Eclipse.  It has a built in debugging UI.  I think this is one of the most important steps in programming, knowing how to debug.  Based on your input; I'd take special note to look around the `cin` lines to make sure you're reading in what you think you're reading in, and processing it the way you think you are

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to learn to use a debugger. Debugging your application is a critical skill for any type of software development.

Comment: `new_way = GenWay(); if(!isInMap(...)) { ways[...] = GenWay(); }` – why do you read another route again? That might be totally unrelated to the previous route, and it might be equal to one already contained! I assume you want `ways[...] = new_way;` instead.

Comment: Try to get used to a consistent naming scheme: `GetWay` <-> `isInMap`: Choose one style, either all functions starting with majuscule or all starting with minuscule, but don't intermix. More common are minuscules (see standard libraries), majuscules especially (but not exclusively) in environments dominated by Microsoft (compare WinAPI or C# code guidelines). Sometimes you'll be using libraries preferring different styles – sure, you won't modify, but within your own code, stay consistent (whichever option you prefer).

Comment: @UKMonkey, @rustyx, I tried it and got some problems with debugger... I try step by step execution, but it just skips the cin input. Passes through it. Even after I try to enter q, seems like it gives a random number. Here is a [pic](https://imgur.com/h1k14J7) (I have entered `4` before it reached `cin>>q;`, and after that. Do I misunderstand how `cin` with debugger works?)

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks a lot for valuable advices! Seems like I just forgot to use const reference, thanks to you.

Comment: @L.F. I've heard about it, but in my opinion that will make readabilty worse, as I don't work with many components now. Though, that's a good advice for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @gdl68 About the `using namespace std;` and readability: It is just a matter of getting used to having qualified identifiers (actually, I personally even consider readability *worse* without). On the other hand, if you look around a little here on SO, you'll find again and again questions where this little line of code actually *was* the source of trouble...

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for telling me about `new_way`, that was the case actually! Though stuff with cin and cout in debugger seem strange to me, you are right. It would be great if you could leave answer below.

Comment: Unrelated hint: There is a function [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to check if a map contains a key. This is (usually) more efficient than iterating through the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortening the code to just the relevant parts:

```
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    cin >> command;
    vector<string> new_way = GenWay(command);
    if(!isVinMap(new_way, ways))
    {
        ways[next_way] = GenWay(command); // <-- (!)
// ...
```

At the marked line, you are producing an entirely new vector, which might be, apart from size, totally unrelated to the one created previously (stored in `new_way`), and possibly worse, might already be contained in the map (there's no new check for!).

Most likely, you intended to insert the way already read previously instead:

```
        ways[next_way] = new_way;
```

> I tried it and got some problems with debugger... I try step by step execution, but it just skips the cin input. [...]

Well, then you could create some dummy data instead, e. g. by using a random number generator:

```
char const* stopNames[] = {"a", "b", "c, /*... */ };
// (you'll need to find out how large it should be to produce sufficient different

std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device()());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> lengths(10, 12);
// (routes with length in between 10 and 12 - or whatever else appears appropriate
//  to you)

std::uniform_int_distribution<> stops(0, sizeof(stopNames)/sizeof(*stopNames) - 1);

//cin >> command;
command = lengths(gen);

//cin >> stop
stop = stopNames[stops(gen)];
```

In other scenarios, you might want to have entirely static data, e. g. just having a `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>>` where you have all data statically stored.

Huh, `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`??? Well, that way you could serve the second (bad) read of ways that has been eliminated by this answer; this shows that test data has to be selected carefully sometimes... If in doubt, you might prefer range-checking (safe) accessors (`std::vector::at`) over non-checking ones (`operator[]`) for retrieving test data.

Reducing complexity of test-data sometimes is appropriate, too, e. g. in given case, you could have used a constant length for all of your routes, possibly resulting in test-data like

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 12>, 10> routes({ ... });
```

producing 10 routes all with length 12...